# How to change loading screen in electron app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, electron

Can someone please tell me how to change this loading screen for an electron app:

[image]

This screen appears when the application started and when there is no network.

Comment: Just add *img* at index.html that will be using as renderer process. Which means this is the result when you are loading the index.html like this
mainWindow.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/index.html');
Right?

Comment: okay got the solution this image was loading from app.global.css